# Open Weather API, site crashes if city is not in the database JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

After following one of tutorials and playing with the code, I got my weather app working. I also get a nice error message if I don’t enter any value and press the button, but if I enter “wrong” value (city is not in API’s database), the app crashes. Is there any chance I could have something like live input search field? For example, if I start typing ''MA…" only cities with those two first letters will appear and I can click on any of them? Also, another problem is that there are some cities with the same name, so I would really need that live search option. If that is too difficult, how could I just stop my app from crashing if city is not in API’s database?

```
import React from 'react';

import Titles from "./components/Titles";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import Weather from "./components/Weather";

const API_KEY = "7b31fc51d965595f7ad494ff430bf91f";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
temperature: undefined,
city: undefined,
country: undefined,
humidity: undefined,
pressure: undefined,
description: undefined,
error: undefined
}
getWeather = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
const api_call = await 
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
const data = await api_call.json();
if (city) {
  this.setState({ 
    temperature: data.main.temp,
    city: data.name,
    country: data.sys.country,
    humidity: data.main.humidity,
    pressure: data.main.pressure,
    description: data.weather[0].description,
    error: ""
  });
} else {
  this.setState({ 
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    pressure: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    error: "Please enter values..."
   });
 }
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="main">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 title-container">
              <Titles />
            </div>
            <div className="col col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 form-container">
              <Form getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
              <Weather 
              temperature={this.state.temperature}
              city={this.state.city}
              country={this.state.country}
              humidity={this.state.humidity}
              pressure={this.state.pressure}
              description={this.state.description}
              error={this.state.error}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
};



export default App;
```

Comment: At which point your application crashes?

Comment: It crashes when I enter city that isn't in the OpenWeather API database and I click on the button to get the weather... as soon as I click, it crashes.

Comment: check your browser console for the error, you need better response checking i assume you do nothing at all

Comment: I did that and I understand first error that

Comment: App.js:19 GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Beograd&APPID=7b31fc51d965595f7ad494ff430bf91f&units=metric 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It says city is not in the database and I know that, but what I don't know is how to fix it.

Comment: I also get this:
App.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
    at _callee$ (App.js:26)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:288)
    at Generator.prototype.(:3000/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:494:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)